# Dynamic css animation for p nth elements tag using Jquery?

Tags: jquery, css, css-animations

I have a Javascript object array containing text which needs to repeat from left to right in a CSS animation. How can I make dynamic CSS using jQuery for the `p:n-th` element?

I want to make a dynamic CSS for the `p:nth` element and keyframes so that it will repeat when all object text done. Please help me. Thanks in advance

```js
var adv = ['SUPERBOWL RESERVATIONS BOOK TODAY AND GET 20% OFF','5 Ways to Maximize Banner Ads with Content. Every type of advertising','5 Ways to Maximize Banner Ads with Content. Every type of advertising','This lists contains the banner content including images and links to destination content.'] ;
console.log(adv);

for (var i = 0; i < adv.length; i++) {
  $('#marquee').append('<p id="">' + adv[i].value + '</p>');
}
```

```css
.marquee p {
  position: fixed;
  font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #333;
  /* text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #000000; */
  filter: dropshadow(color=#000000, offx=1, offy=1);
  transform: translateX(100%);
  -moz-transform: translateX(100%);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
}
.marquee p:nth-child(1) {
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation: left-one 100s 8.5s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation: left-one 100s 8.5s linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation: left-one 100s 8.5s linear infinite;
  animation-delay: 2s;
}
.marquee p:nth-child(2) {
  animation: left-two 100s 8.5s ease infinite;
  -moz-animation: left-two 100s 8.5s ease infinite;
  -webkit-animation: left-two 100s 8.5s ease infinite;
  animation-delay: 2s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
}
.marquee p:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation: left-three 100s 8.5s ease infinite;
  -moz-animation: left-three 100s ease infinite;
  -webkit-animation: left-three 100s 8.5s ease infinite;
  animation-delay: 2s;
}
@-moz-keyframes left-one {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: translateX(100%);
  }
  10% {
    -moz-transform: translateX(0);
  }
  40% {
    -moz-transform: translateX(0);
  }
  50% {
    -moz-transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes left-two {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: translateX(100%);
  }
  50% {
    -moz-transform: translateX(100%);
  }
  60% {
    -moz-transform: translateX(0);
  }
  90% {
    -moz-transform: translateX(0);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes left-three {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
  }
  90% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
  }
  10% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
  }
  40% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="marquee" id="marquee"></div>
```

Comment: Could you replace the `<? php echo json_encode($msg); ?> ;` in your fiddle with a sample of the *actual* output so we can see what we're dealing with. The snippet is pretty redundant at the moment

Comment: i have updated my javascript object array with text..now using these text i am appending with 'p' tag..now make a dynamic css for p:nth element when n is no of pth element